# JPA Creation - Hibernate not showing in platform

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to create a JPA project with Hibernate as the persistence provider. But when i click on the Platform, it is not showing Hibernate. It shows Generic and EclipseLink under Platform dropdown box. What should I do to get Hibernate under the dropdown box ? Any thoughts on this? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you installed JBOSS Tool ?

Comment: no..i have not installed jboss tool..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason you are not getting Hibernate perspective or option because you have not installed Hibernate JBoss Tools.

You can download them from [here](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html)

You can also install by clicking `"Help" -> "Eclipse Marketplace" and search "Jboss Tools"` and install them all.

Comment: I installed Jboss Tools and it is working now. Thanks a lot Makky.

Comment: It is not necessary install all the components of "JBoss Tools", uncheck all options and select only the "Hibernate Tools" option

Answer (score 3):

If you are using eclipse, you need to download 'hibernate tools' from eclipse marketplace.
Then you can choose hibernate.

Comment: i installed Jboss tools and it is working now.. thanks ilan for sharing the info..