# Which JPA implementation does Eclipse use?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I know the difference between JPA and specific implementation for example `Hibernate` or EclipseLink, but what I am interested in, when I download for example Eclipse JAVA EE version, and then in my project use `javax.persistence` package, which implementation does it use? My guess would be EclipseLink or OpenJPA but how do I know?

I am interested in this because I compared performance of Hibernate and javax.persistence package (just few thousand of rows from db) and the performance gap from my point of view was quite big (about a second)

Comment: at compile time it uses none. at runtime, it uses what you configure it to use, as per the dropdown. And this is not the site for performance comparisons; all implementations can be configured to give great performance.

Comment: Yeah I know I am no professional in database performance I just did the basic test and it really suprised me how big the difference was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose it in the JPA Facet pane by using the Platform dropdown. See [Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jpt.doc.user%2Ftask_create_new_project.htm).

[image: JPA Facet Page screenshot]

If you want to use Hibernate, you have to add it manually in the Eclipse Marketplace. See: [JPA Creation - Hibernate not showing in platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198117/jpa-creation-hibernate-not-showing-in-platform)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse EE will bundle EclipseLink via the JPA facet you can add to a project, but other than that it doesn't really provide any specific implementation (you can configure it to provide other implementations if you configure with facet with other user libraries). Your implementation is provided either by libraries, or your app server that you are deploying to. For longer term, a more strategic approach would be to explicitly include an implementation either through dependencies (maven) or referring to/using libraries provided by your app server.